# cakephp 3 populate list with data from another table

Tags: mysql, list, cakephp, dynamic

I'm trying to populate a list from data from a table.  The table is called fields, and the column I'm trying to grab is called CALIBER_F.  My controller has the following:

$caliber = $this->fields->CALIBER_F->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('caliber'));

However, I'm getting this error:
Error: Call to a member function find() on null.  The column has no null values. Ideally I'd like to be able to populate the list from multiple tables.  Normally my select would look like this:

SELECT CALIBER_F FROM public.FIELDS WHERE CALIBER_F IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT CALIBER FROM public.GUN WHERE CALIBER IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT CALIBER_AMMO FROM AMMO WHERE CALIBER_AMMO IS NOT NULL;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might need to recheck your syntax. if the database table name is "fields", the model name should be Fields.

In case you're writing this in some other controller(apart from FieldsController.php), load the model on runtime using $this->loadModel

```
   $this->loadModel("Fields");

   $caliber = $this->Fields->find("list", [
      "keyField" => "id",
      "valueField" => "CALIBER_F"
   ])
   ->toArray();

   $this->set(compact('caliber'));
```

This should certainly fix your issue.

Peace! xD